# RabbitMQ behavior when One Queue binded with Multiple Exchange for Same message

Tags: java, rabbitmq

We have the following scenario. 
Queue: Q1

Q1 binds to Exchange1 and Exchange2.

Message A published to both Exchange1 and Exchange2.

We have Q1 Consumer defined. 
How will be the behavior in this case. Does the message consumed twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the message consumed twice?

Yes.

If you publish the message to both Exchange 1 and Exchange 2, and both of these exchanges push the message to Q1, then you consumer will have 2 messages to consume.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. We had a situation in which the queue was supposed to bind to a new exchange. But we forgot to remove with old exchange. We had a strange situations that caused us to think on this.